# Android 2 cursors 1 listview

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview

I have an app that populates a listview from a cursor.  One of the items is gallons of water.  Recently I had a request to use liters as well so I wrote a settings page that lets people choose units.  I want to have the cursor still show the number of units of water in the listview but I also want to have a texview next to the number to say gallons or liters, whichever the second cursor pulls.  Is it possible to have one cursor put 10 items in a listview then another cursor put one item in that same listview?

Comment: Why not just add the items you want added to the list into one ArrayAdapter... Then use it to populate the list?

Comment: I was using a simplecursoradapter and I just did away with it.  It took a little more programming but I am no longer using a listview.  I decided to just populate each item into a string then put that into a textview.  It works fine now.